# How do I use weighted least squares in a matrix formulation of a multiple regression analysis?

Tags: multiple-regression, weighted-regression

If the coefficients of OLS multiple regression can be determined by: β = (X'X)^−1 * X'Y, then what formula/matrices would be used for WLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the diagonal matrix ${\bf W}$ containing the weights corresponding to each row of ${\bf X}$. We have:
$${\boldsymbol \beta} = ({\bf X}^T{\bf W}{\bf X})^{-1}{\bf X}^T{\bf Wy}$$